# Selecting rows from tables without knowing names in Postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql

I wrote a function that concatenates the name of a table + a two-digit cost center code. There are many tables for each cost center - total about 1000. So now I need to construct 'select' statements for these tables outside the function after it's executed.  Since I don't really know the table names programmatically once I exit the function, does anyone have suggestions on how to find these tables and construct select statements under these conditions?

Comment: Why not have a single set of tables and add the cost center as an additional column to filter your queries by?

Comment: How does your function know the table names?

Comment: Each cost center has multiple tables which are merged together as a single table per cost center.  Each cost center has millions and millions of records so it's not practical to put all cost centers into a single table.  The function takes a table name - regardless of the name - and appends the cost center to the end of the table name, but table names vary by cost center so we cannot rely on table names being the same across cost centers. So, the function does not know the table name.